# Apple Wallet Passes backend Web services

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, passkit

I have been setting up my backend web services for Apple wallet Passes with NFC enabled. Is there any open sources available for for the complete set up which includes push notification, device registration, creating, updating and downloading passes and all services? can anyone help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For updating passes, there is an implementation of the Passkit Web Service included in the [Wallet Companion Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html) from Apple.

I have not used it, but [jpasskit](https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit) is the only open source implementation I have seen.

Comment: Wallet companion Files are last updated on 2011. Does jPasskit have push notification registration and its services?

Comment: From briefly looking at the code, it looks like they have an implementation of the Apple Push Notification Service, along with storing the push token when a device is registered.